# Logitech Webcam C615 SDK/API

Tags: java, c#, sdk, webcam, logitech

I need program an application that it uses a Logitech webcam, I have a C615 and its configuration applications allow change different parameters as brightness, gain, zoom,...

Anybody knows if exists an SDK to connect this (C++, C#, Java,...) for use and change on demand these parameters?

Thank you so much.
Àlex

Comment: See here https://community.logitech.com/s/feed/0D53100005mTv7SCAS There is no answer about Logitech SDK